# Is this sequence of functions convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the sequence of functions $\begin{equation}
   f_n(x) =
   \begin{cases}
     2nx & ;0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2n}\\
     2 - 2nx &  ;\frac{1}{2n} < x \leq\frac{1}{n} \\
     0 & ;\frac{1}{n} < x \leq 1 
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

is $f_n(x)$ pointwise convergent?

I don't think it is, because for $n\to\infty$ we have $f_n(x)=2nx$ or $f_n(x)=2-2nx$ so it wouldn't even be well-defined.

On the other hand, what do the terms $f_{\infty}(0)=2\cdot\infty\cdot 0$ or $f_{\infty}(0)=2 - 2\cdot\infty\cdot 0$ even mean?

I'm a little bit confused here.

Comment: you can't use $\infty$ as a real number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=0$. Then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$.

Let $0\lt x\le 1$. Then for large enough $n$ we have $f_n(x)=0$, since $\frac{1}{n}\lt x$ for all large enough $n$.

So our sequence converges pointwise to the identically zero function on $[0,1]$.